# Updating a double in a text file

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I have an `ArrayList` with user accounts stored into a text file, each account represents a virtual bank account.

What is the most efficient way for me to update the balance of an account, after a user decides to add, or withdraw money?

I have successfully retrieved the balance, just need to save it.

Here is what I have so far, most of the magic happens in the ATM and Bank classes

**ATM CLASS**

```
public class ATM {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Bank bank = new Bank();
    double balance = 0;

    // Welcome screen
    String dash = "-------------------\n";
    System.out.print(dash);
    System.out.print("Welcome to the Bank\n");
    System.out.print(dash);
    System.out.println("Do you have an account with us? (y/n) ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer = scanner.nextLine();

    while (true) {

    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

        System.out.println("Username: ");
        String userName = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("PIN: ");
        int pin = scanner.nextInt();

        bank.hasUser(userName, pin);

        if (bank.hasUser(userName, pin)) {
            User.balance = bank.getBalance(userName, pin, balance);
            bank.menu();
            break;
        } else if (!bank.hasUser(userName, pin)) {
            System.out.println("\n** Incorrect username or password, please try again**\n");
        }

    } else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {

        Bank.newUser();
        break;

    } else {
        System.out.println("\nThat's not an option, do you have an account with us?");
    }

    }


}

}
```

**BANK CLASS**

```
public class Bank {

public static void newUser() {

    // new user is created
    String dash = "-------------------\n";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your full name below (e.g. John M Smith): ");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Create a username: ");
    String userName = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your starting deposit amount: ");
    double balance = scanner.nextDouble();

    System.out.print(dash);
    System.out.print("Generating your information...\n");
    System.out.print(dash);

    int pin = PIN();
    String accountNum = Bank.accountNum();

    User user = new User(name, userName, pin, accountNum, balance);

    // new user gets added to the array list
    Bank.users.add(user);

    try {

        File file = new File("users.text");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        bw.append(String.valueOf(Bank.users + "\n"));
        bw.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void menu() {

    while (true) {

        System.out.print("\n1");
        System.out.print(" - Acount Summary     ");
        System.out.print("3");
        System.out.print(" - Deposit Money\n");
        System.out.print("2");
        System.out.print(" - Withdraw Money     ");
        System.out.print("4");
        System.out.print(" - Exit\n\n");
        System.out.print("I would like to: \n");

        Scanner bscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int mc = bscanner.nextInt();

        if (mc == 1) {
            System.out.print("Your current balance is: $"
                    + User.getBalance() + "\n");
        } else if (mc == 2) {
            System.out.print("Enter withdrawl amount: ");
            double wd = bscanner.nextDouble();
            User.balance -= wd;
            System.out.println("\n$" + User.getBalance()
                    + " is your new account balance.");
        } else if (mc == 3) {
            System.out.print("Enter deposit amount: ");
            double dp = bscanner.nextDouble();
            User.balance += dp;
            System.out.println("\n$" + User.getBalance()
                    + " is your new account balance.");
        } else if (mc == 4) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.out
                    .print("\nThat's not an option, please select an option listed below!\n");
        }
    }
}

public boolean hasUser(String userName, int pin) {

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "users.text"));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");
            if (userName.equals(tokens[1])
                    && pin == Integer.parseInt(tokens[3])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

public double getBalance(String userName, int pin, double balance) {

    boolean r = false;

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("users.text"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine())!= null) {
            line = line.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
            String[] num = line.split(",");
            if (userName.equals(num[1]) && pin == Integer.parseInt(num[3])) {
                r = true;
            }

            if (r) {
                balance = Double.parseDouble(num[4]);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return balance;
}

// array list for users
static ArrayList users = new ArrayList();
{

};
}
```

[image: Screenshot of text file, description of each item below]

Comment: Using an actual database.

Comment: Not allowed to, this is a project, also I'd have no clue how, kind of an amateur still...

Comment: If you can already pull info out and change it, what is confusing about putting it back?

Comment: In case of textfiles simply overwrite it with the complete & updated data. Don't try to replace lines or parts of a file.

Comment: @csmckelvey I wish that I had an explanation, but I just can't seem to get it to work... I have an idea in mind, but it seems really inefficient to me, and I was wondering if there was an easy way that I'm missing out on to change it.

Comment: Well if the only problem is saving data to a file, please remove all the irrelevant code you posted, post just the parts you tried using to save the data, and then we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: @zapl Thats what I was thinking, so should I load all the users into an `ArrayList` before I make changes, delete the file, and then reload them into the text file?

Comment: @csmckelvey Deleted what I thought was useless

Comment: You don't have to delete the file. The default way of writing a file will overwrite the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do this would be to keep the accounts in ArrayList (as you are doing) and then just save the whole text file again. If you are dealing with small amounts of data it would not take very long. (A better way to think about optimizing is not re-opening the file every time you need to access it's data, just keep it in an array list).

Also, you may not need to save the file after every change. If you are the only app using the file try just saving it when you get closed.

If you want really good performance you will need a data base.

Comment: ok I was planning to do this, but isn't everything in the text file considered a string? So would I have to manually load and assign each attribute? Is there a way to save the users as an object?

Comment: @ks23, What you need to do is make some class to represent the items. Then when you go through the file you need to get the relevant data from the string and put that in the class. I can't tell you how to do it in java sorry (my java is bad).

Answer (score 0):

You have to write to the file i dont see any of that...

```
    File fileWriter = new File("user.txt"); //recall it or whatever
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileWriter, true)); //APPEND

        writer.println(balance, name, eg...);

    writer.close();
}
```

Printwriter is more effective than filewriter, and filewriter is needed anyhow but this will work, also if you want to do multiples people then just for loop it, and dont forget to close!
 for (int i = 0; i < users; i++) { //the for loop

if you still have issues then ask again i've done dbms and the other answer is wayyy off. Hope this helps!

Comment: I believe that I am writing to the file in the Bank Class, inside of the newUser method, so every time a new user is created they would get stored inside of the file. I'm still struggling with pulling down each user, and storing them into a user object that's unique. Do I have to pull every user from the list down? I was thinking to just pull the one that has a matching username and password, then when the user is done adding or withdrawing money, overwrite the user in the file with the updated info... problem is I'm not even sure where to begin.